# Can a jailbroken iPhone and a non-jailbroken iPod Touch operate on the same machine/itunes

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, jailbreak, itunes

I have a iPod touch that is not jailbroken. Recently I was given a jailbroken iPhone by somebody. I want to know if I can use both devices with the same iTunes installed on my laptop? Will using a jailbroken iPhone mess up with the iPod touch syncing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it'll be fine.  I did that for a while after I got my iPad and still had my jailbroken iPhone 3G.

Jailbreaking, at least at its basic level, doesn't mess with most of the basic functions of the device such as syncing.  All bets are off if you install some JB app that is specifically meant to alter some part of the sync process, but even then it's very unlikely it will cause trouble of the iPod.

Comment: Thanks. I synced and it worked. So far no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have a jailbroken iPod and do (uncommonly) experience syncing problems. It uncommonly displays an error message saying "Could Not Connect to This iPod" and I just re-connect and all is well.